# what does setObject function do in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, blocks, php-5.4, methods

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
```

this code call 'customer/widget/name.phtml' file and convert into html

but what **setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml()** can do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the classes in Magento extend `Varien_Object`.
This class make use of the magic method [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) that allows you to call non-existent methods on class instances.
Using this magic method, `setObject($something)` is actually translated into `setData('object', $something)` that just does `$this->_data['object'] = $something`.

You can later read this value by using `getObject` that through the same magic of `__call` translates into `$this->getData('object')` that is `$this->_data['object']`.

To summarize, these methods are just magic setters and getters for the current instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the block class in question `Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Name` then you will see that there are no methods defined for `setObject()` or `setForceUseCustomerAttributes()` in that, or any parent class.  This means that the 2 set calls are just using magic methods to set data against the object and this is normally to make it easily accessible in the relevant template in the case of blocks.  In the class `_construct()` method you can see the template defined for the block:

```
$this->setTemplate('customer/widget/name.phtml');
```

If you then look at this template you can see calls to `$this->getObject()` which just pulls the data assigned by the block class.  There aren't any calls to `getForceUseCustomerAttributes()` in the template but you can soon track these down.  This is called in method `_getAttribute()` of the block class and this method is in turn called in many of the other block class methods.  Finally these other block class methods are called from the template.

So where you see `->set...` in relation to blocks and there is no method defined in the block class or parents you are making a magic method call to set data against that object, most of the time to make it accessible to the related template.